# JPA - OneToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Given the following two entities :

```
class Parent {
       @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
       private Set<Child> children;

       (...)
}


class Child {
       @ManyToOne
       private Parent parent;

       (...)
}
```

I would like two tables in the database. One table for the parents and the other one for the children. But Hibernate creates three tables: one for the parents, one for the children and one for joining them (table with two fields).

Even if I put `@OneToOne` on the parent attribute in Child class, I still get the same result.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **mappedBy="parent"** attribute in annotation is missing for building the bidirectional association.

```
class Parent {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Child> children;

   (...)
}

class Child {
   @ManyToOne
   private Parent parent;

   (...)
}
```

Comment: What if you have Person OneToMany Items, and an item can only be owned by one Person. Would the Item have ManyToOne or a OneToOne ? To me it appears as if it should be OneToOne there Child is now ( considering you can only have one parent)

Answer (score 3):

Add the `mappedBy` property to the `@OneToMany` in the `Parent` class. This makes the `Child` be the owning side.

In `Child` add the `@JoinColumn` annotation to the `parent` field in order to declare the foreign key column name in the child table.

From the JavaDoc on `@OneToMany#mappedBy`:

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

Unidirectional relations need a join table, but in your case it's bidirectional, thus it's required.

Comment: Hibernate generates automatically a correct FK for me : parent_id. Is it important to use JoinColumn ?

Comment: @Stephan no, you'd not need to use `@JoinColumn` if the generated column is fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

given your foreign key column in the children table is called "parent_id", try

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private Set<Child> children;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: it's good to have it. hibernate has no knowledge of foreign key constraints. so hibernate can only guess (use name pattern assumptions) which column is used for that relation. therefore it's good to be explicit.